# phonegap websocket doesn't work

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, websocket, phonegap-plugins

Ok i have tried in every way to put the phonegap-websocket plugin in my phonegap project and there's no way it could work.


I had install the plugin like it is explained in that page [here](https://github.com/mkuklis/phonegap-websocket), it seems the plugin is correctly installed, if i launch the cordova plugin list it appears, i have added the plugin in the config.xml too, i have added the src to the cordova_plugin.js and to the cordova.js file in the index.html, i have build the app and add a simple a script in the index.html

## JS

```
var ws=new WebSocket("ws://echo.websocket.org");
ws.onopen=function(){
    alert('open')
    ws.send('hi')
}

ws.onmessage=function(){
    alert('hello')
}
```

if i put alerts before,between or after the two methods the cellphone where i test the app, appears, but the ones inside the methods not, like they didn't work, if anyone know why i really appreciate the explanation.

Comment: plugins aren't loaded until the event `deviceready` is fired. Are you waiting for this event to fire before calling these methods?

Comment: i'll try tomorrow i'll let you know if it's the problem thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll write the answer but the merit must go to Dawson London, the project as i write it work right but it need to be launched after the device is ready.